# How to close a window with a Event Handler from a MenuItem

Tags: java, javafx, window, menuitem

I have a `MenuItem` that i want to use to close the window being displayed, i have created the `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` and the `MenuItem`, `Menu`, and `MenuBar` but cannot work out a way to make it close the window.

I've tried

```
class ConnctFourMenuItemHanlder implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            MenuItem item = (MenuItem) event.getSource();

            if (item.equals(quit){
                ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            }
}
```

but it says:
"Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Node"

I was expecting it to just close the window

Comment: An object cannot extend both `MenuItem` and `Node`. One of those casts always fails regardless of the source. You need to get your hands on the window/some node in the scene displayed in the window you want to close using means other than the event source...

Comment: yes i want to close the window so how to i get my hands on the widow through the ```MenuItem``` ?

Comment: Don't try to get the window through the `MenuItem`. Use a reference to the scene, a node in the scene, or the window itself that's visible to your handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Event Dispatcher System.Your menu Item will listen for events,and then you can dispatch the to the correct methods. [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD47_hq75q0)